# static_assert on indices know at compile time

Tags: c++, c++11, runtime, compile-time, static-assert

Is there a way to statically assert on indices known at compile-time and run-time assert otherwise? Example:

```
template <class T, int Dim>
class Foo
{
    T _data[Dim];
    public:
        const T &operator[](int idx) const
        {
            static_assert(idx < Dim, "out of range"); // error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant
            return _data[idx];
        }
};

int main()
{
    Foo<float, 2> foo;

    foo[0];
    foo[1];
    foo[2]; // compiler error

    for (int i=0; i<5; ++i)
    {
        foo[i]; // run time assert when i > 1
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks, updated the question.

Comment: You can look at __builtin_constant_p for GCC, but it is not probably going to get you a perfect solution because there are some really weird behaviors with GCC when you try to do what you're suggesting.

Comment: Your `foo[2]` access is not done in `constexpr` context, and your operator is not `constexpr` either. You won't get a compile time error. To achieve your goal, use `assert` (which will give a non-`constexpr` call error if false) instead of `static_assert`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible obtain what do you want with a single function.

Even if you develop a `constexpr` function, I don't think your are able to detect when is executed run-time and when executed compile time and act in a different way.

But you can develop different functions.

By example, a template `get<>()`, where the template argument is the index, that can be used only with an index known at compile-time and that can perform a `static_assert()`, and an `at(std::size_t)`, that can receive an index computed at run time with a run time check.

En passant:

1) I suggest, as usual in STL, the use of `at()` for a bound checked access and an `operator[]()` for a bound unchecked access

2) and I suggest the use of an unsigned index or you have to check that the index is `>= 0`.

The following is a working example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

template <class T, std::size_t Dim>
class Foo
 {
   private:
      T _data[Dim];

   public:
      T const & operator[] (std::size_t idx) const
       { return _data[idx]; }

      template <std::size_t IDX>
      T const & get () const
       {
         static_assert(IDX < Dim, "out of range");

         return this->operator[](IDX);
       }

      T const & at (std::size_t idx) const
       {
         if ( idx >= Dim )
            throw std::range_error("out of range");

         return this->operator[](idx);
       }
 };

int main ()
 {
   Foo<float, 2U> foo;

   foo.get<0U>();
   foo.get<1U>();
   //foo.get<2U>(); // compiler error

   for ( auto i = 0U ; i < 5U ; ++i )
      foo.at(i); // run time exception when i > 1

   return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for that answer, it works just fine. Just curious, would it be possible to write a function with the behavior of both `get` and `at` ,depending on whether the index parameter is known at compile time?

Comment: @sharvey - I don't think it's possible; if you discover that can be done, please, show me how.

Answer (score 3):

You could simply throw an exception or assert. It will fail compilation in constexpr context. This only works if the condition for throwing can be evaluated in constexpr context.
Note that there is a bug in some versions of gcc that prevent the throw from working.